# Алгоритм жеребьевки турнира по настольному теннису

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

У меня имеются 16 команд которые сыграли уже 6 игр. Имеются данные с какими командами они уже играли. Вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача в том чтобы сгенерировать уникальные пары команд которые будут играть следующие игры или хотя бы игру. Важно то чтобы эти команды до этого еще не играли дург с другом.

Пишу все на JS но если есть решение на другом языке то это не проблема.
Какой будет алгоритм? Как решить эту задачку?)

Comment: Взять список команд и удалить оттуда команды, с которыми уже играли. Это даст вам "хотя бы игру"

Comment: Это понятно, но это никак не решает задачу, только немного упрощяет)

Comment: Как это "не решает"? Если эту операцию повторить для всех команд, вы получите список возможных партнеров для всех команд.

Comment: Сейчас попробую для каждой команды. Но пока все равно не понимаю решения.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Думаю, что автор имеет в виду под игрой - 8 пар команд, а в общем случае таких может и не оказаться. Мне пока навскидку кажется, что тут в задаче что-то от двудольного графа имеется - типа, из первоначально полного графа на каждой игре удаляются пачка ребер, после чего нужно опять сделать граф двудольным...

Comment: @Harry Да, вы правы, я имел ввиду под одной игрой 8 пар или на все последующие игры сразу, тоесть 8*N.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Я сделал набор всех возможных партнеров для игроков, но как теперь каждому партнеру выбрать уникального соперника чтобы за тур каждый из них играл только один раз?
Вы можете навести пример или написать алгоритм в ответе пожалуйста?

Comment: Нужен дополнительный массив с командами, с которыми игр еще не было и после проведения игры удалять их и добавлять в массив, с которыми игры были

Comment: @Dimmi выше написано "Взять список команд и удалить оттуда команды, с которыми уже играли."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант могу предложить такое решение на JS:

```js
const playedMatches = [
  [8, 3, 10, 1, 13, 11],
  [7, 6, 13, 0, 11, 5],
  [3, 8, 5, 7, 12, 9],
  [2, 0, 8, 14, 9, 10],
  [11, 5, 14, 13, 7, 6],
  [6, 4, 2, 9, 14, 1],
  [5, 1, 9, 10, 8, 4],
  [1, 9, 12, 2, 4, 14],
  [0, 2, 3, 15, 6, 13],
  [10, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2],
  [9, 11, 0, 6, 15, 3],
  [4, 10, 15, 12, 1, 0],
  [13, 14, 7, 11, 2, 15],
  [12, 15, 1, 4, 0, 8],
  [15, 12, 4, 2, 5, 7],
  [14, 13, 11, 8, 10, 12]
];
const maxTeams = playedMatches.length;  // Всего команд
const teamNumbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]; // Вспомогательный массив - номера команд
const aviableMatches = []; // Массив доступных соперников для каждой команды
const pairsFlat = []; // Плоский массив найденных пар
const pairs = []; // Итоговые пары

// Заполняем массив с доступными соперниками для каждой команды
for(let i = 0; i < maxTeams; i++){
  const aviableTeams = teamNumbers.filter(function(team){
    return (team !== i) && (playedMatches[i].indexOf(team) === -1);
  });
 aviableMatches.push(aviableTeams);
}

// Рекурсивная функция поиска пар 
function findMatches(){
  let teamIndex;
  if(pairsFlat.length >= maxTeams) return true; // Нашли все пары
  for(teamIndex = 0; teamIndex < maxTeams; teamIndex++){
    if(pairsFlat.indexOf(teamIndex) === -1){
      const aviableTeams = aviableMatches[teamIndex];
      const teamPair = aviableTeams.find(function(team){
        return pairsFlat.indexOf(team) === -1;
      })
      if(teamPair === undefined) continue; // Нету доступной пары, ищем дальше    
      pairsFlat.push(teamIndex); 
      pairsFlat.push(teamPair);
      if(findMatches()){ // Ищем рекурсивно
        return true;
      } else {         // При такой паре не нашли решения. Удаляем пару и продолжаем поиск
        pairsFlat.pop();
        pairsFlat.pop();
      }
    }
  } 
  return false; // Не нашли решения
}

// Проверяем!
if(findMatches()){
  for(let i = 0; i < maxTeams; i += 2){   // Нашли! Заполним массив пар
    pairs.push([pairsFlat[i], pairsFlat[i+1]]);   
  } 
  console.log('Found pairs of teams:');
  console.dir(pairs)
} else {
  console.log('No pairs!')
}
```